# What causes the fish shell to change input while typing?

Tags: fish

I understand, that when I start typing that fish can give me either *[auto-suggestions](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_autosuggestions)* or *[tab completion](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_tab_completions)*.

But: I also noticed that sometimes I get **updates** to my command line while typing. Example: I have a command a lengthy command line to enable some tooling of mine, lets say it looks like:

```
 python3 whatever.py -bla -blub --property fubber:blub
```

I start typing "py2" and fish suggests

```
 python3 whatever.py -bla -blub --property fubber:blub
```

OK. So I use alt-left arrow to *accept* up to

```
 python3 whatever.py -bla -blub
```

and now I start **typing** `--property` ( not accepting, typing that word ). Thing is: as soon as typed the last char (y) from property fish will somehow insert content into command line. Worse: it also happens frequently, that the whole isn't showing correctly any more in my iterm session - I actually have *no* way of seeing the exact current command before hitting enter.

I know that the above isn't exactly an MCVE - but I can't disclose my actual command here, and I was unable to create that MCVE. In that sense, my question boils down to: which events make the fish shell insert content into the "current" command?

For completness:

- I am running `fish, version 2.7` on Mac Os 10.13.3, installed via brew
- default bindings
- I am sure that just pressed "y", no modifier key added to that

But I am also unable to repro at this point in time. So, although I am very sure that I didn't dream this up, I consider this to be a strange hick-up for the moment that hopefully stopped bugging me for now.

Comment: I've used (and contributed to) fish for several years. Never seen or heard of anything like you're describing. It sounds like you're possibly accidently pressing [ctrl-y] or [alt-y] rather than just "y" in your example. What fish version? Default of vi key bindings? Does it happen if you start fish with no customizations via `sh -c 'env HOME=$(mktemp -d) fish'`?

Comment: You can use the `complete` command to view or edit command completions.  There might be some weird expression in there that accounts for the behaviour you’re seeing.  Arguments for `complete` that it uses to populate the suggestion list can be commands themselves, so there’s potential for complex behaviour to be elicited from a code completion, which can be very useful, but not if it’s not intended.  To delete all code completions for `python3`, use `complete --command python3 --erase`.

Comment: Thanks, I will check out your suggestions tomorrow.

Comment: This just sounds like a bug; can you please post a screenshot, or file an issue at github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell?

Comment: @ridiculous_fish Will do so, in case I ever get to repro the issue. I keep playing around, but I can't get to the behavior where just typing the last character of that word corrupted the whole command line. Probably more work is required to uncover this easter egg ;-|

Comment: One source of rendering problems is the use of emoji and similar chars because the width calculated by fish may differ from that of your terminal.